# How to Send Confirmation Emails to Users after Form Submission?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, comment-form, contact, email-verification

I would like to run a confirmation e-mail on Contact Form 7

What I want is: Once a form has been submitted, the visitor who sent the form must confirm it by going to the email address. A confirmation link is sent to the e-mail address. And after confirming, the message reaches. Also, after you submit the form, the user will be shown the information text on the form to check the email address.

How can I do this?

Comment: You'll need to check with the plugin developers directly.

Comment: Thank you. I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Contact Form 7 is a plugin for WordPress. You'll need to ask the people who made that plugin. :) https://contactform7.com/support/

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at the hooks of the [Contact Form 7 plugin website](https://contactform7.com/).
Browse the documentation for the actions you need.

Have a look at this topic: [how-to-hook-into-contact-form-7-before-send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926252/how-to-hook-into-contact-form-7-before-send)

All you need to do is to add your link with the hash into the e-mail.
In addition, also have a look at "[wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)".
That is the mechanism which triggers an e-mail.

So, catch the e-mail before it is being sent, add your link to it, then trigger the actual mail.

I know, this isn't a complete answer, but adding your own work to it should get you in the right direction.